# Why can't i normalize my data using preprocessing.normalize?

Tags: machine-learning

code:

```
df['Miles'] = preprocessing.normalize(df['Miles'])
```

Error msg:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[33.3304678  33.3304678  33.3304678  ...  3.00959404  3.00959404
  3.00959404].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sklearn.preprocessing.normalize is vector norm normalization. By default it use L2 Norm which is $x_{norm}=\sqrt{\Sigma{x_i^2}}$. For example, if there's one vector $(1,2,3)$, then the $x_{norm}=\sqrt{1^2+2^2+3^2}=3.7416$, then if you normalize the vector, it would be $(\frac{1}{3.7416},\frac{2}{3.7416},\frac{3}{3.7416})$.

If that's what you want, try

```
# convert to numpy array with shape(rows,1)
df_array = df['Miles'].values.reshape(-1,1)
df['Miles'] = preprocessing.normalize(df_array,axis=0)
```

Note that setting axis=0, otherwise it would be done column-wise and you will get all 1 vector.

I think you may want to scale the vector rather than normalization, try mean-std scale by `sklearn.preprocessing.scale`, max-min scale by `sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale`. Be sure that you reshape the array first.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this might not be the normalization you are looking for sklearn.preprocessing.normalize is a tool to make sure that the feature vector has length 1.

According to sklearn.preprocessing.normalize

> Scale input vectors individually to unit norm (vector length).

If you are still persistent the fix is simple. Simply do

```
df['Miles'] = preprocessing.normalize(df['Miles'].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

But I can guess your result will be a feature vector of all 1.